# PHP: Checking if value inside of an array already exist

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, multidimensional-array

**Written Explanation:** 
I need to check whether or not the Quiz ID ($quiz_id) exist and if the Quiz Progress = "1", if so, execute a block of code, else do something else.

There are multiple rows of data. My object is to prevent my update script from publishing another row of data if the quiz_id exists and the progress=1

**UPDATED: Code**

```
add_action('ssquiz_finished', 'after_quiz_done', 10, 5);

function after_quiz_done( $post_id, $quiz_id, $user_id, $questions_right, $total_questions )
{
    $postID = $post_id;
    $result = $questions_right / $total_questions * 100;

    $field_key = "field_52a22a06c7837";
    $hello = "user_".$user_id;
    $value = get_field($field_key, $hello);
    $value[] = array(
                "quiz_name" => get_the_title($postID),
                "quiz_id" => $quiz_id,
                "quiz_score" => $result,
                "quiz_progress" => "1"
            );

    update_field($field_key, $value, $hello); //Script that updates the row (adds rows)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You"re looking for `isset` http://www.php.net/isset

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to reflect new information in question.

```
add_action('ssquiz_finished', 'after_quiz_done', 10, 5);

$quiz_ids = array();

function after_quiz_done( $post_id, $quiz_id, $user_id, $questions_right, $total_questions )
{
    if (!in_array($quiz_id, $quiz_ids))
    {
        if (isset($value['quiz_id') && $value['quiz_progress'] == 1)
        {
            $postID = $post_id;
            $result = $questions_right / $total_questions * 100;

            $field_key = "field_52a22a06c7837";
            $hello = "user_".$user_id;
            $value = get_field($field_key, $hello);
            $value[] = array(
                "quiz_name" => get_the_title($postID),
                "quiz_id" => $quiz_id,
                "quiz_score" => $result,
                "quiz_progress" => "1"
            );
            //Everything is good, let's add this quiz_id to the quiz_ids array
            $quiz_ids[] = $quiz_id;

            update_field($field_key, $value, $hello);
        }
        else
        {
            //$quiz_id wasn't set or the quiz progress wasn't equal to 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //fail, because $quiz_id already exists
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but no luck there. there cannot be any duplicate quiz ID's!

Comment: OK, that changes things significantly -- can you update your example to include the wrapping code and how you're looping though the multiple quiz_ids? In a general sense, you could create a list of quiz ids above the loop and add each quiz id to it, then so a simple `in_array()` to check if it's there. But without more code, this may or may not work.

Comment: r3mus - It's inside a function. I'm using wordpress as the CMS.

Basically, If the person's score($result) is >= 80, they pass the quiz(quiz_progress). In passing the quiz, I don't want the update script to add as they passed it again.

Comment: I'm getting this php warning error: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\wp-acf-test\wp-content\themes\twentythirteen\functions.php

Comment: Whoops, missed a `)` at the end of that line.

Comment: I changed `if (!in_array($quiz_id, $quiz_ids)` to `if (!in_array($quiz_id, $quiz_ids))` with two )) at the end.

Comment: I changed it. I got no errors, but the script didn't execute the update_field function.

Comment: Since you didn't provide the update_field function, I can't help you there. Best to troubleshoot by using `echo` or `print_r` at various points in the script to see what's going on -- particularly right before you call that function to see what $field_key, $value, and $hello are displaying.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have one set of actions if the quiz_id is set, and if it isn't then a new row is added. Try

```
if(isset($value['quiz_id']) //if the quiz id exists in the array
{
    if($value['quiz_progress'] == 1){
        //exists and is in progress code
    else{
        //code for exists but isn't in progress yet
}
else
{
    //perform code for if there is not entry
}
```

If this doesn't work you may wish to clarify the question...

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I mean though. If the result is >= 80, The person passes(quiz_progress turned into a "1") the quiz and cannot take it again. If its below zero, then the script doesn't update anything and the person can take the quiz again.